# show parent when child image has lazyloaded

Tags: html, css, vue.js, lazy-loading

How i could make the parent div/element hidden until the child image has lazyloaded?

I am currently using vue-lazyload, ive been able to lazyload the image itself, but the parent div's height is wrong, and it is different every time.

is there a specific way to do this? or should i add a min-height property to the img, that seems to work, but id have to make that responsive.

as an example i have the following code:

```
<a href="/example" class="class-with-border" v-lazy-container="{ selector: 'img' }">
    <img data-src="example.png" lazy="loaded">
</a>
```

in this example the parents styling (border etc. load while child img has not yet loaded, so you see the height of the parent change, which isnt very pleasing.

Comment: please share some code

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim ive added an example

Answer (score 0):

You can use loading option (src of the image while loading).
like this:

```
Vue.use(VueLazyload, {
    preLoad: 1.3,
    loading: 'dist/loading.gif',
    attempt: 1,
  });
```

And Also read the github page for more options.